# Capturing Build System Results - file_regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to catch the error line number (5 in this example) of the following output error  build in Sublimetext2 :

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\new12.x (5): 'x' undeclared identifier
```

However I do not not how to create the  Perl-style regular expression.

I have tried :

```
"file_regex": "^([^:]+):([0-9]+):",
```

Can any one help me to create the regex ?

Source :

See [Documentation](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html)

Comment: Try `^(\\S+)\\s*\\(([^()]+)\\)`. OR [`^([^ ]+)[ ]*[(]([^()]+)[)]`](https://regex101.com/r/xL5vF0/2).

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks it works ! could you propose your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
^([^ ]+)[ ]*[(]([^()]+)[)]
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL5vF0/2)

It matches *and captures into Group 1* one or more characters other than a space from the start of string (file name), and then match whitespace(s) followed by an opening `(`, and then match *and capture into Group 2 any characters other than `(` and `)`, one or more times, and then match a literal `)`.

Comment: In case there can be a space inside the file name, you can  try using [`^([^\\\\]+[^:]+)[ ]*[(]([^()]+)[)]`](https://regex101.com/r/xL5vF0/3) or [`^([^\\\\]+[^:]+?)[ ]*[(]([^()]+)[)]`](https://regex101.com/r/xL5vF0/4) (to trim spaces from the file name).